# How to extract a value from a type Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a type

```
type expr =   
Const of int 
| Var of string    
| Bin of expr * binop * expr
```

also

```
type binop = 
 Plus 
| Minus 
| Mul 
| Div
```

and

```
type value =  
Int of int               
| Closure of env * string option * string * expr
```

Binop performs an operation on two exprs and I need to write an eval function that takes in a closure and expr and returns a value

ex.

```
 let evn = [("z1",Int 0);("x",Int 1);("y",Int 2);("z",Int 3);("z1",Int 4)];;
val evn : (string * Nano.value) list =
  [("z1", Int 0); ("x", Int 1); ("y", Int 2); ("z", Int 3); ("z1", Int 4)]

# let e1 = Bin(Bin(Var "x",Plus,Var "y"), Minus, Bin(Var "z",Plus,Var "z1"));;
val e1 : Nano.expr =
  Bin (Bin (Var "x", Plus, Var "y"), Minus, Bin (Var "z", Plus, Var "z1"))

# eval (evn, e1);;
- : Nano.value = Int 0
```

The issue Im having is that the function needs to return INT int instead of an actual into value.

This is what I wrote so far

```
let rec eval (evn,e) = match e with
| Const a -> Int a
| Var x-> Int (lookup (x,evn) )
| Bin( Var x, Plus, Var y) ->   Int ( eval(evn,Var x) + eval(evn,Var y) )
| Bin( Var x, Minus, Var y) -> Int ( eval(evn,Var x) + eval(evn,Var y) )
| Bin( Var x, Mul, Var y) ->   Int ( eval(evn,Var x) + eval(evn,Var y) )
| Bin( Var x, Div, Var y) ->  Int ( eval(evn,Var x) + eval(evn,Var y) )

;;
```

lookup looks up x in the closure evn and returns its value
the issue Im having is I need to perform integer operations in the bin matches but since eval returns types of value I cant do that. How would I change the code in the last four matches to make it be able to do the arithmetic and return type Int of int after that's done?

Answer (score 2):

You need something like

```
let x =
  match eval (evn, Var x) with
  | Int x -> x
  | _ -> failwith "runtime error"
in

let y =
  match eval (evn, Var y) with
  | Int y -> y
  | _ -> failwith "runtime error"
in

Int (x + y)
```

in each of the match cases. You should probably factor out this pattern-match into a function that you can call repeatedly:

```
let get_int = function
  | Int i -> i
  | _ -> failwith "runtime error: expected an integer"

... Int ((eval (evn, e1) |> get_int) + (eval (evn, e2) |> get_int))
```

It should make sense that you have to do this runtime check in your evaluator – in your representation, there is no reason why a variable can't be mapped to a closure in `evn` instead of an integer.

Also note that, contrary to your question, `evn` itself is not a closure. It's usually called the "environment". The closures are the values constructed by `Closure`, and they carry environments, among other things – I think you simply had a typo, though.

I'm assuming that you will generalize the `Var x` and `Var y` to two expressions `e` and `e'` in the future, of course.

Comment: Also, I can't help but wonder if "`evn`" shouldn't be "`env`".

Comment: got it to work used a helper function that took exprs and turned them into ints then did operation then back to exprs

Answer (score 2):

```
let rec eval (evn,e) = match e with
| Const a -> Int a
| Var x-> Int (lookup (x,evn) )
| Bin(  el, Plus,  er) ->
    let Int cl=eval (evn,el ) and Int cr=eval (evn,er ) in
    Int (cl+cr)
| Bin(  el, Minus,  er) ->
    let Int cl=eval (evn,el ) and Int cr=eval (evn,er ) in
    Int (cl-cr)
| Bin(  el, Mul,  er) ->
    let Int cl=eval (evn,el ) and Int cr=eval (evn,er ) in
    Int (cl*cr)
| Bin(  el, Div,  er) ->
    let Int cl=eval (evn,el ) and Int cr=eval (evn,er ) in
    Int (cl/cr)
```